# Which data can I unhesitatingly send over a GET request?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, get

I create a VueJS application with express and sequelize to access a mysql database (currently running with XAMPP). I have a database which consist of 3 tables:

```
users:    [id (primary key), name, email, family_id (foreign key)]  
families: [id (primary key), name]  
hobbies:  [id (primary key), name, user_id (foreign key)]
```

All of these IDs are auto_increment so the first user registered gets the ID 1 and so on.
Every user within the same family (so with equal family_id) is allowed to see the hobbies of the other family members. I have a SQL query, which gives me all the family members. On my websity I have a simple drop down menu, where I can select the member. With a GET request I then want to retrieve all hobbies of the selected member.
Now I can basically decide if I use the id or the email for the request parameter e.g. `/api/hobbies/:id` or `/api/hobbies/:email`. Email reveals more private information while id reveals information about my internal strucutre like "At least (id) number of users exists.". I think it is better to use the id.
Maybe there is also the possibility to assign a random id (not auto increment) in the database? But I dont know how to to this.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you send as a parameter to a GET request is private. Those parameters are part of the URL you GET, and those URLs can be logged in various proxy servers, etc, all over the internet without your consent or your users' consent.

It seem to me that family members' hobbies can be sensitive data. What if the whole family likes, say, golf? A cybercreep could easily figure out that a good time for burglary would be Saturday afternoons.

And if your app does GET operations with autoincrementing id values, it's child's play for a cybercreep to examine any record they want. Check out the Panera Bread data breach for example. https://krebsonsecurity.com/2018/04/panerabread-com-leaks-millions-of-customer-records/

At a minimum use POST for that kind of data.

Better yet, use a good authentication / session token system on your app, and conceal data from users if they're not members of that family.

And, if you want to use REST style GET parameters, you need to do these things to be safe:

1. Use randomized id values. It must be very difficult  for a cybercreep to guess a second value from knowing a first value. Serial numbers won't do. Neither will email addresses.
2. Make sure unauthenticated users can see no data.
3. Make sure authenticated users can only see the subset of data for which they're authorized.

My suggestion to avoid REST-style GET parameters comes from multiple security auditors saying, you must change that.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in this are, but aren't POST request only to push data to the database e.g. when creating a user and GET is used when you want to fetch data from the db? For authorization is use JWTs.